# how to pass an array with fork in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have an array and i want to send it to a child process. 
But the problem is i get it in child process as a string.
How can i fix it? 
Thanks.

parent file

```
const {fork} = require('child_process');

var botsList = [];
fork('./app.js', [botsList]);
```

child file:

```
var botsList = process.argv[2];
console.log(typeof botsList);
```

Comment: Args are always strings, you need to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.js` will receive a string, but depending on the complexity of `botsList`, you could use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

`index.js` will do something like:

```
const {fork} = require('child_process');                                                                                                                                                                

var botsList = ["botA", "botB", "botC"];

fork('./app.js', [JSON.stringify(botsList)]);
```

And `app.js` will do parsing of the argument:

```
let botsList = process.argv[2];                                                                                                                                                                         

try {                                                                                                       
     botsList = JSON.parse(botsList);                                                            
} catch (e) {                                                                                               
     console.log('Could not parse string as JSON');                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                                                       

console.log(botsList);                                                                              
console.log(typeof botsList);
```

And the output:

[image]